# How to set the offset value of a child?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to set the offset value of the child. I have a div class under which I have three child created dynamically. Now I want to set offset value. But I am not able to achieve it. Below is the code that I am using:

```
$(curelement).find('.priority-icon').offset({ left: activitymonthpos });
```

here "curelement" is the current element i.e. $(this).The **.priority-icon** is a class that contains three indexed value i.e [0],[1], and [2].

The above code set the single offset value for each child. i.e for [0], [1], [2] index. as I am using the parent class that contains all the child.I also tried the below code but it is not working and I am not getting the desired result:

```
$(curelement).find('.priority-icon')[i].offsetLeft=976;
```

The cshtml is as:

```
<div class="timeline-bar">
            <div data-bind="foreach:UpcomingActivities()">
                <div class="priority-icon completed" id="priorIcon">
                    <div class="detail-popup">
                        <strong data-bind="text:Title()"></strong>
                        <p data-bind="text:Description()">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bar-steps">                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am actually stuck here and is not able to figure out what needs to be changed. Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.offset` is read only

Comment: Hi slash197, I am able to set the offset left value for the parent class..so I guess it is not readonly

Comment: Use CSS classes: add them and remove. In specific class you could define `position: relative; left: 200px;` for example.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh: i tried the position function of css but it is not giving me the desired output. this was the reason i opted offset

Comment: @Yash `.offsetLeft` is pure JS and sets a property, `.offset()` is a jquery method and is read only

Comment: Usually it's wrong to manipulate styles by JS. You'd better manipulate CSS classes by JS and declare all your styles in CSS.

Comment: @slash197: but when I used the jquery offset method, I am getting the desired results for a single child